# pandas hwo to groupby create other columns by counting values of existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

I got to know how to do this in R(
[How to make new columns by counting up an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54510200/how-to-make-new-columns-by-counting-up-an-existing-column)), but I'd like also to know how it works in python as well.

When the original table is like below

```
 userID   cat1    cat2
    a        f       3
    a        f       3
    a        u       1
    a        m       1
    b        u       2
    b        m       1
    b        m       2
```

I group them by userID and want it come like

```
userID   cat1_f  cat1_m  cat1_u  cat2_1  cat2_2  cat2_3
a        2       1       1       2       0       1
b        0       2       1       1       2       0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.melt('userID')
        .groupby(['userID','variable','value'])
        .size()
        .unstack([1,2], fill_value=0))
#python 3.6+
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
#python bellow
#df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(a,b) for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=7, step=1)
  userID  cat1_f  cat1_m  cat1_u  cat2_1  cat2_3  cat2_2
0      a       2       1       1       2       2       0
1      b       0       2       1       1       0       2
```

Alternative with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = df.melt('userID')
df = pd.crosstab(df['userID'], [df['variable'], df['value']])
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```